# jQuery UI Tab not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am creating jQuery UI Tabs but all the tabs show static with all the contents, the tab is not working correctly, not selectable. (I don't have enough reputation to post image ><) The data is from XML file.

Here is the code: (I have all the link and script in the head)
in HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul id="tabtitle">
    </ul>
</div>
```

My js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    $.get('data.xml', function(d){
        $(d).find('page').each(function(){

            var $page   = $(this),
            title       = $page.find('title').text(),
            description = $page.find('description').text(),

            var tabtitle = '<li><a href="#tab-' + i + '">' + title + '</a>' + '</li>';
            $('ul#tabtitle').append($(tabtitle));

            var tabcontent = '<div id="tabs-' + i + '">';
            tabcontent += '<p> ' + description + '</p>' ;
            tabcontent += '</div>';
            $('#tabs').append($(tabcontent));

            i++;
        });
    });
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pages>
    <page>
        <title>Tab1</title>
        <description>content for Tab1 here</description>
    </page>
    <page>
        <title>Tab2</title>
        <description>content for Tab2 here</description>
    </page>
    <page>
        <title>Tab3</title>
        <description>content for Tab3 here</description>
    </page>
    <page>
        <title>Tab4</title>
        <description>content for Tab4 here</description>
    </page>
</Pages>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the li reference to `tab-n`, but the related div are called `tabs-n`.

So there is not matching and you'll face the issue; you can check the problem by comment the tabs method and checking the DOM.

Try changing this:

```
var tabtitle = '<li><a href="#tab-' + i + '">' + title + '</a>' + '</li>';
$('ul#tabtitle').append($(tabtitle));

var tabcontent = '<div id="tabs-' + i + '">';
```

into:

```
var tabtitle = '<li><a href="#tab-' + i + '">' + title + '</a>' + '</li>';
$('ul#tabtitle').append($(tabtitle));

var tabcontent = '<div id="tab-' + i + '">';
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WcgyA/

### EDIT

Because you are loading your xml by a jQuery `get`, you have to execute your `tabs` method at the end of the get callback function.

Comment: Your demo is very helpful! I fixed this mistake but my way to read data from xml is buggy so that it still don't show correctly. do you know how to fix it ? Thanks.

Comment: I fixed the second bug: $( "#tabs" ).tabs(); should be inside the get {}. =)

Comment: Added at the answer; in the fiddle the problem not exist because the xml is hardcoded an not get using jQuery get.

Answer (score 0):

in  tag you use tab-1 (href attr) in div id="tabs-1" ?

i think changing

'

`<a href="#tab-' + i + '">`

to

'

`<a href="#tabs-' + i + '">`

would do the trick